# PanGestureHandler: Bottom to top resets to bottom and then animates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I have attached the snack for better clarity. I am trying to achieve an animation similar to the iOS/Android notification bar.

I am successfully able to drag the handlebar to the bottom using the below-given code:

```
const translateY = cond(
  eq(gestureState, State.END),
  [
    cond(
      greaterThan(dragY, 0),
      set(
        dragY,
        runTiming(clockY, dragY, velocityY, 400, gestureState, () => {
          console.log('f1');
        }),
      ),
      set(
        dragY,
        runTiming(clockY, dragY, velocityY, 0, gestureState, () => {
          console.log('f2');
        }),
      ),
    ),
    set(offsetY, dragY),
    dragY,
  ],
  cond(
    eq(gestureState, State.BEGAN),
    [stopClock(clockY), finalDragY],
    finalDragY,
  ),
);
```

But, while trying to animate it from the bottom, it just snaps the handlebar to the bottom and then animates it to the top. On debugging further, I realized that the translated position resets and then it animates.

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/5yj_4ZjwR)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue and update the snack with the solution. Basically, there were a couple of issues.

1. On dragging the handle from top to bottom, the value of translationY would be negative as you are panning in the opposite direction. So, to fix it, I added the negative value with the total height `add(400, dragY)`:

   ```js
       set(
           dragY,
           runTiming(clockY, add(400, dragY), velocityY, 0, gestureState, () => {
             console.log('f2');
           }),
         )
   ```
2. The `translateY` used to reset to the bottom and then start animating. It never used to get updated with the value returned from `add(400, dragY)`. To fix that, I added it to the section where the clock was running and I wanted to capture the position:

   ```js
     function runTiming(
     clock,
     value,
     velocity,
     dest,
   ) {
     const state = {
       finished: new Value(0),
       velocity: new Value(0),
       position: new Value(0),
       time: new Value(0),
       frameTime: new Value(0),
     };

     const config = {
       duration: 500,
       toValue: new Value(0),
       easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
     };

     return [
       cond(
         not(clockRunning(clock)),
         [
           set(state.finished, 0),
           set(state.velocity, velocity),
           set(state.position, value),
           set(config.toValue, dest),
           set(state.time, 0),
           set(state.frameTime, 0),
           startClock(clock),
         ],
         [
           // if the clock is already running we update the value, in case a new value is captured from panning
           set(state.position, value),
         ],
       ),
       timing(clock, state, config),
       cond(state.finished, [
         stopClock(clock),
         // reset animation
         set(state.finished, 0),
         set(config.toValue, 0),
         set(state.time, 0),
         set(state.frameTime, 0),
       ]),
       state.position,
     ];
   }
   ```